# iPhone AVFoundation to RTMP

Tags: iphone, rtmp

So I am creating an iPhone app that records video using AVFoundation and I need to be able to stream that to a RTMP Media Server.  Any ideas/thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Jim

Answer (score 1):

use Adobe flash media live encoder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by intercepting the actual captured frames and throw it into the network. Destination could be another iPhone, Android based who's able to play H264 / AAC, any computer, or streaming server like crtmpserver

Or to make your life easier you can visit www.evostream.com they offer this functionality just the way you want it customized.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this iPhone project https://github.com/cleitaum/LiveShare

Comment: Rather than just posting a link, could you explain in greater detail why this would be useful here? The link might die at any time, and having a detailed description of the project could help us find a replacement when that happens.